# Ruby on Rails Tutorial - 6.3.1 - Tests Not Passing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railstutorial.org

when attempting to pass the tests as per the tutorial I'm following I receive the following error message.

```
Nicolas-Krauses-iMac:sample_app fuzzy_bunnys$ bundle exec rspec spec/
/Users/fuzzy_bunnys/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `load': /Users/fuzzy_bunnys/Documents/rails_one_click/sample_app/spec/models/user_spec.rb:6: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting => (SyntaxError)
/Users/fuzzy_bunnys/Documents/rails_one_click/sample_app/spec/models/user_spec.rb:62: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end
```

I've double checked lines 6 and 62 in my user_spec.rb file and can't find any unmatched end keywords or any out of place brackets. So I'm at a bit of a loss as to what's going on. The user_spec.rb code is below. Any help is much appreciated!

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do

  before do
     @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com" )
  end

  subject { @user }

  it {should respond_to(:name)}
  it {should respond_to(:email)}
  it {should respond_to(:password_digest)}

  it {should be_valid}

  describe "when name is not present" do
    before {@user.name=" "}
    it {should_not be_valid}
  end

  describe  "when name is too long" do
    before {@user.name="a"*51}
    it {should_not be_valid}
  end

  describe "when email is not present" do
    before {@user.email=" "}
    it {should_not be_valid}
  end

  describe "when email format is invalid" do
    it "should be invalid" do
        addresses = %w[user@foo,com user_at_foo.org example.user@foo. 
                        foo@bar_baz.com foo@bar+baz.com ]
        addresses.each do | invalid_address|
            @user.email = invalid_address
            expect(@user).not_to be_valid
        end
    end
  end

  describe "when email format is valid" do
    it "should be valid" do
        addresses = %w[user@FOO.COM A_US-ER@f.b.org frst.lst@foo.jp a+b@baz.cn]
        addresses.each do |valid_address|
            @user.email = valid_address
            expect(@user).to be_valid
        end
    end
  end

  describe "when email address is already taken" do
    before do
        user_with_same_email = @user.dup
        user_with_same_email.email = @user.email.upcase
        user_with_same_email.save
    end

    it {should_not be_valid}
  end
end
```

Comment: What version of ruby are you using? It could be that your ruby doesnt support the new hash syntax

Comment: Indeed, what is the output of `ruby -v`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your `ruby --version` is < 1.9.3 (or whenever the new colon syntax was introduced)

To fix, either install a newer ruby, or convert the hash to the older style (`name: "Example User"` becomes `:name => "Example User"`)

Evidence - Line 6 is the line with the hash(`name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com"`), and its expecting `=>` instead of `}` which might be the end of the block on the next line.

Comment: @zishe I didnt down vote you, and that is not a fair reason regardless. And whoever downvoted you had a point (enough that you deleted your post). You should try to be less rude and more open to learning new things

Comment: For me it was a downvote without a reason (except it was an author and answer didn't work). Sorry, i can reverse it if you make some edit. It's revenge thing, happens:)

Comment: Forced to admit, you have a great answer.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I checked my Ruby version and its 2.0.0, I haven't had any syntax issues pop up in any of my tests earlier in the tutorial. All of these errors seemed to show up after I modified my gemfile and added 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.1.2'. I'd read elsewhere that the issue could possibly be a corrupted gem install, but clearing out all my gems and reinstalling them doesn't resolve it. At a bit of a loss.